# What is the best practice for JWT and Sanctum authentication at same time az Laravel?

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have a Laravel application that is currently working with JWT authentication, but I would like to include Sanctum for a third system as well. They both use the same routes and expect the same data, so I wish he didn't have a separate route.

JWT Package: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Sanctum Package: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication

Comment: Why would you need to have two different authentication schemes?

Comment: Because JWT is used by the user and always gets a new one, and the sanctum is used by a third app. Because jwt has an expiration date, and if the server shuts down for some reason, don't have to generate new tokens.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your arguments. You should just choose one or the other, it doesn't make sense to implement multiple authentication schemes.